# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Replacing an existing task that may have already been used by other plugins is not supported

Tags: gradle, marklogic, ml-gradle

I am using gradle6.7 and ml-gradle 4.1.0 version in my my project but i am getting error given below at the the time of Deployment:

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Replacing an existing task that may have already been used by other plugins is not supported.  Use a different name for this task ('mlLoadSchemas')."

Answer (score 1):

Gradle 6 does not allow for tasks to be replaced. ml-gradle declares a task named mlLoadSchemas. So either another plugin (DHF?) or something in your build.gradle file is trying to replace that task with another task, which Gradle 6 disallows.